# jquery marquee to rotate alterning sentences

Tags: jquery, marquee

I made a marquee in HTML. The problem I have is that it spins only to the half of the second sentence and then stops and restarts again, on chrome. On firefox i get all sentences on below another. Besides that the text scrolls pretty laggy, and I was more looking for a sliding cool text banner for news an announcements, not that crap.

So I googled and found that jQuery is what I need and that setting an array and variables could help. Thing is I didn't find anything I could use, besides I don't really understand much beyond basic HTML modifications.

```css
#marqs1 {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    margin:0px;
}
#marqs2 {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
#marqs2:hover {
    color: #e59834;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<marquee id="marqs1" behavior="scroll" direction="left" loop="0" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    Welcome to XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - Your Source for bla bla bla. Find the latest news <a id="marqs2" href="#################">here</a>
</marquee>

Sentence 2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - contact us if you need help <a id="marqs2" href="#################">here</a></marquee>

Sentence 3 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - and so on bla bla bla <a id="marqs2" href="#################">here</a></marquee>
```

Does somebody have an example for me that I could use and modify?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using marquee in HTML is deprecated (it mens, that no one knows, when browsers stop support for it), you can use some JS/CSS insted e.g - http://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2013/05/06/simulate-marquee-tag-in-css-and-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link, I hope this may help you.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/Simple-Text-Slider-Rotator-with-jQuery-CSS.html